# laravel 4.1 get categories on initial page load

Tags: php, laravel

Hello im making my first laravel application and i wanted to see how i can call a function in the controller and load categories as part of my headers.

So i have a controller and function that will get the info from the database but now i need to do it where everytime someone loads up the website this function is called and the categories are loaded into my header.blade.php template

I know i can place my call from the global.php file in the start directory but how do i call the exact controller and function and load the results in the view.

Comment: you need to assign that controller in your routes.php file.  it is in the app directory

Comment: Yes but how do i assign it. I have other controllers and route::get('/login', LoginController ..... but what would i put for this if there is really no route for this its just getting categories on page load to load in the header

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to build a master layout.  Check this out http://heera.it/laravel-4-view-composer-master-layout#.VFgoEu_n9Ds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your code to **function __construct()** inside your controller, this function will always be called when you bind your controller to your route using route::get('/', array('uses' => 'Controller@function'));

If you are using blades, you can share your data by using **View::share('data', $data);**

Comment: I dont have a route though. This is for a included header template that should have a list of all the categories that will exist on every single page

Comment: Yeah it's ok, anyway, **__construct** will always be called if your controller has been initialized.

Comment: Ok then how do i pass the results to the includ/header.blade.php view

Comment: use **View::share('data', $data);**, and then in your view, you can access it normally, **$data['columnName']**.